# How to set different coefficients for different physicalCells?

Tags: fipy

I generated a 2D model with gmsh and set up different physics groups. When I try to

```
coeff = CellVariable(mesh=mesh)
coeff.constrain(k_Au,where=mesh.physicalCells == 'ring')
```

I get the error

```
if numerix.shape(value.where)[-1] == self.mesh.numberOfFaces:

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

How can I set different coefficients for my different physicalCells?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the syntax quite right. Try

```py
coeff.constrain(k_Au,where=mesh.physicalCells['ring'])
```

Also, `.constrain()` is intended for boundary conditions. To set different values of a coefficient, I would do

```py
coeff.setValue(k_Au, where=mesh.physicalCells['ring'])
```